# Error after upgrading from laravel 5.4 to laravel 5.5

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5, php-7.1

I have just updated an Laravel project from Laravel version 5.4 to 5.5. After upgrading I am getting error where the error message is:

```
Line: 2445 
File: /home/vagrant/Projects/Media365/harlib-core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php 
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::newQueryForRestoration()
```

I have no clue why I am getting this error. Even there is nothing but only comment at line 244`Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php` file.

Answer (score 3):

If this error is caused from a queued job and you're using [supervisor](http://supervisord.org) to run the queue worker then I was having the same problem. I was running the queue worker on **supervisor** before I upgraded to 5.5 from 5.4. Supervisor keeps the **old version** and you need to **restart it**:

```
supervisorctl restart <program_name>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have already solved this issue by changing by queue driver from database to redis.

Comment: Thank you so much @Fayçal. It avoids some useless search time.